# How to center a rotated div inside a table element with a specific width?

Tags: html, css

Having a heap of trouble trying to center a rotated div that is inside a `td` within a table, while giving it a specific `max-width`. I am able to center it perfectly with `vertical-align: middle;`. Although, when I attempt to change the width of the `td`, the div is then off-center.

**CSS:**

```
.rotated {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}

td {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

td.rotatedParent {
    background-color:red;
    max-width: 36px;
}
```

**What I have tried:**

I have tried rotating only the `td`, then only the child `div`, then only the child `p`, although neither of these worked. Tried messing around with `displays` and `positions`, yet still no luck. I cannot use static values such as `margin` and `padding` since there is no way telling how large the `tr` height will be.

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N2748/)

Comment: Could possibly `transform-origin: (x) (y);` be of help?

Comment: I fixed a little bit. Is there still something wrong in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/N2748/1/

Comment: @DanielLisik - The main thing that isn't working is applying a width to the rotated `td`. If you apply `max-width:30px;` to the `rotatedParent`, you will notice that they go off-center.

Comment: You mean the text? Because the two bottom red boxes seem to be pretty well centered, no?

Comment: They are perfectly centered, yes. But apply `max-width:30px` to the `td.rotatedParent` class and you will see that the text gets uncentered.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Will return in a few minutes. :)

Comment: My question is all about applying a `max-width` to the `td` without the text being uncentered.

Comment: Does this do? http://jsfiddle.net/N2748/3/

Comment: @DanielLisik - Perfect mate! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job:

**CSS**

```
.rotated {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:left top;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin:left top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:left top;
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform-origin:left top;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin:left top;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 36px;
}

.rotated p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 36px;
}

td { vertical-align: middle }

td.rotatedParent {
    background-color: red;
    min-width: 36px;
    max-width: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

tr { height: 200px }
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N2748/4/)**